# Inputing 2d column array into 2d numpy array

Tags: numpy

what is the "pythonic" way of inputting 2d column vector to a 2d numpy array (actual 2d array)? example problem below:

```
mu = np.array([[1, 2]]).T    
sigma_points = np.zeros((2, 2))
sigma_points[:, 0] = mu
```

EDIT:

found it:

```
  sigma_points[:, [0]] = mu
```

Comment: Nothing looks particularly wrong with your code snippet. What do you mean by *inputing*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it:

```
  sigma_points[:, [0]] = mu
```